# date format with timezone

Tags: python, date-formatting

How do I format a date in python to look like this: `weekday:month:day(number):HH:MM:SS(military):EST/CST/PST:YYYY`? I am familiar with strftime(), but I am unsure how I would handle the HH:MM:SS and EST/CST/PST.

example of how I am trying to get the date to look:

```
Sun Mar 10 15:53:00 EST 2013
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strftime` to output a formatted string representation:

```
print time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
```

A list of the format codes can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 3):

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", gmtime())
```

This will produce

> Fri Mar 22 21:10:56 Eastern Standard Time 2013

You'll have to settle for the long name of the timezone unless you want to use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). I suppose it's worth noting that [timezone abbreviations aren't unique](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).