# change date format with timezone to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am familiar with strftime however they require date to be in datetime format. In my case I get data that looks like `01/Oct/2019:07:34:34 +0900`. I would like to convert it into `2019-10-01 07:34:34`.

**NOTE:** my date is in object datatype.

I've read [date format with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579599/date-format-with-timezone) and
 https://www.guru99.com/date-time-and-datetime-classes-in-python.html however they both assume I have datetime format that looks like datetime(2019, 10, 1, 07, 34, 34)

thanks to [month name to month number and vice versa in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa-in-python/21938128).

I've created a function that changes the format

```
import calendar
month_dict = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))

def date_formatter(date):
    day, month, year_and_time = date.split()[0].split('/')
    year, hour, minute, second = year_and_time.split(":")

    month = month_dict[month]

    return f'{year}-{month}-{day} {hour}:{minute}:{second}'
```

then since I am working with dataframe, use apply + lambda to apply to all rows.

```
df['new_date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda row: date_formatter(row))
```

This works perfectly and people might be telling me to just use it, I am just curious if there is any alternative way.

Comment: Can you specify what is the datatype of `01/Oct/2019:07:34:34 +0900` that you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the date you provided is a string, then use

```
from datetime import datetime

myDate = '01/Oct/2019:07:34:34 +0900'

dt = datetime.strptime(myDate, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
dt_to_string = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(dt_to_string)

2019-10-01 07:34:34
```

Theres this for future use: https://strftime.org/

EDIT:
Saw you were in a dataframe, use

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTimeColumn'], format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
```

Comment: Thanks. using the df version, it is closest to what I want. I want to get rid of +09:00 at the end,

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

old_date = "01/Oct/2019:07:34:34 +0900"
new_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%b/%Y:%X %z").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")

print(new_date)
```

> 2019-10-01 07:34:34

Check out this cool page: https://strftime.org/

Comment: thanks but I don't see the diff from earlier answer by Randy

Comment: Randy's post is 2 minutes earlier, only saw it when I refreshed.